# Variance of a weighted uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given a weighted uniform distribution, where it is a 60-40 mixture of uniform(0,7.5) and uniform(7.5,10),

I have found the mean to be $$E(X) = 0.6(7.5/2) + 0.4((10+7.5)/2)$$

How do I find the variance? Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the definitions:

$\begin{align}
\mathsf {Var}(X) & = \mathsf E\big(X^2\big)-{\mathsf E(X)}^2
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E(X) & = \frac{6}{10}\int_0^{7.5}\frac{1}{7.5}x\operatorname d x+\frac{4}{10}\int_{7.5}^{10}\frac{1}{2.5}x\operatorname d x
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E(X^2) & = \frac{6}{75}\int_0^{7.5}x^2\operatorname d x+\frac{4}{25}\int_{7.5}^{10}x^2\operatorname d x
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out I was working with the wrong method (the one you saw in the thread earlier)